# I keep receiving emails about a job message I archived

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, jobs-messages

I recently received an invitation to apply for a job through SO and followed the instructions to apply outside SO.  I archived the message, but I keep receiving emails about it, including the below threat to change my account setting from actively looking to open.

Is there a way to archive a message and indicate that you have followed up with the company outside SO so it doesn't change the actively looking status?

[image: Email I received days after archiving the message]

Comment: This warning and "autochanging" is ridiculous. I suggest adding [tag:feature-request] and opt for a `I applied over other channels` Button in this dialog.

Comment: Wow, that bullying behaviour is really poor.

Comment: What happens if you click _I'm interested_. Does it try to get you to apply via SO? What about _I'm not interested_? Surely that wouldn't contact the company to say "Omnilord isn't interested", it would just stop showing you the ad?

Comment: @PatrickArtner we're working on ways that we can better track external applications so users aren't bothered with this. Re. downgrading status; this is there because if we don't then candidates appear to employers as actively looking, even if they've long since found a position. It's a tough balance to strike; freshness of candidates to employers and not nagging candidates about updating their information - that's why we try to make it as automatic as possible.This is one of the places where we could do better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a few things to address here:

First off, you archived a message and we still kept sending you reminder emails. Given that this is a concrete action on the message by you, the recipient, then it feels like a bug to keep telling you about the message. I'll look at getting that one addressed asap.
Additionally when we do send a reminder we tell you that we'll mark you as "*open, but not active looking*" if you don't perform any action. I get that this can feel a little intimidating, but let me give some detail about the reasoning behind that...

To receive messages from employers on the /jobs platform you need to have a minimally complete Developer Story and have set one of two states in your [Job Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) - **Actively looking right now** or **Open, but not actively looking**.

Those two states mean very different things in the employer-facing side of the product. Active users are weighted towards the top of the search results and are generally given more visibility than those that aren't actively looking. It's in everybody's best interest to make sure the information is up to date - candidates hear from employers if they're more visible and it doesn't benefit either party if the information is stale.

To determine whether you're active or not we keep a note of activity you perform on /jobs - doing things like viewing job details, executing searches, applying to jobs or replying to messages all factor into this. We try not to bother you about it unless we really have no information to go on. If we don't have that information we send an email asking if you're still looking after 3 weeks and then after another 3 weeks we set your status to **Open, but not actively looking**.

Unfortunately, in this case, we're hassling you irrespective of how recently you visited us or indicated your status.

We're discussing the best course of action internally, I suspect we might remove the copy on those messages but I'll update this post when I have more information.

**UPDATE:** we've changed the copy in the email, to remove the last sentence "If you don't take any action, your status will be updated to **open, but not active looking**". In addition, if you don't respond to the message we won't actually update your status: we have other ways to track this that are more accurate and we'll be using those instead.

Finally, marking a message as archived is now used as a signal to prevent reminder emails from being sent.

Thanks for your feedback, hoping this makes things a little more palatable for you in future!